# Automatically restart Snap server after changing a file

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework

I have started learning a bit about the snap framework, I found some tutorial on blaze snap and want to build a little web-app.

**The tedious thing when changing code in the html section is that I have to
`Ctrl+C` the existing Snap server, then `cabal run` to restart it again is there an easier way to do that.**

I found the following util [watchr](http://github.com/owainlewis/watchr) which allows for running a command after a certain file is being changed - which is definitely useful but I don't quite know how to apply it in this situation.

Get a minimal working example - use the `snap init barebone` command and substitute the `src/Main.hs` with

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module Main where

import           Control.Monad (forM_)
import           Control.Applicative ((<|>))
import           Snap.Core
import           Snap.Util.FileServe
import           Snap.Http.Server
import           Snap.Blaze (blaze)
import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified Text.Blaze.Html5 as H

main :: IO ()
main = quickHttpServe site

site :: Snap ()
site =
    ifTop testHandler <|>
    dir "static" (serveDirectory ".")

testHandler :: Snap ()
testHandler = blaze $ H.docTypeHtml $
    do H.head $ H.title "SnaptestBlaze"
       H.body $ do H.p "Blaze makes Html"
                   H.ul $ forM_ [1..10::Int] (H.li . H.toHtml)
```

and make sure to have `snap-blaze` and `blaze-html` in the corresponding `*.cabal` file.

I also saw that there is a package `snap-loader-dynamic` which sounds promising, but I could not build the application for the dependencies required and the dependencies in the cabal sandbox had different hash values.

I saw that there exists `stack` to eventually replace `cabal` in the long run, but I have not had enough time to check wether `stack` could do automatic rebuild & restart.

If the environment where I am developing is relevant: Linux (Mint) + cabal-sandbox.

Comment: Just to double-check: does `cabal install -fdevelopment`, as suggested in [the quick-start guide](http://snapframework.com/docs/quickstart), work for you?

Comment: one moment I'll have to try

Comment: I do not know why it is building -but as I wrote I tried using the snap-loader-dynamic, nevertheless I tried modifying the Site.hs from the freshly built app, and I also modified the login.tpl (just added a word) but it did not recompile. - To not make sure I'll be a fool - i opened the site in chrome - and then it recompiled - lazyness - bit me (again) the recompilation only happens when the site is requested! - thanks!

Comment: could you make your comment an answer - I would like to accept it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Snap itself comes with this capability built-in. Assuming you initialized your project with `snap init`, just build your project by

```
cabal install -fdevelopment
```

and it will reload itself on the fly as necessary.

Comment: Also see this [faq entry](http://snapframework.com/faq#how-do-i-run-my-app-in-development-mode).

Answer (score 1):

Daniel's answer is definitely the right one.  However, if you want reloading that doesn't involve code changes, that is also possible too.  See [this blog post](http://devblog.soostone.com/posts/2013-06-17-snap-template-reloading.html) for an example.

Comment: Thanks - I will give this blogpost definitely some attention!